# Buffer overflow with setuid bit enabled

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am trying to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability on a testing environment.

Although I have managed to write a specific address at the return address, the stack is executable and I have the shell code ready.

When i use them, the shell I get has my own UID and not the executable's owner privileges.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

man bash:

> If  the  shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, ... and the **effective user  id  is set to the real user id**.

See also [(Ubuntu) setuid bash doesn't work](https://serverfault.com/questions/93883/ubuntu-setuid-bash-doesnt-work), [Setuid bit seems to have no effect on bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash) and [many other resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+setuid+protection).